# Error when installing dlib

Tags: python, cmake, dlib

I am trying to install dlib on a virtual environment on a mac.

When I run  `./compile_dlib_python_module.bat` this is the error I get:

```
Scanning dependencies of target dlib_
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/dlib.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/matrix.cpp.o
[ 89%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/vector.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/svm_c_trainer.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/svm_rank_trainer.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/decision_functions.cpp.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/other.cpp.o
[ 93%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/basic.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/cca.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/sequence_segmenter.cpp.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/svm_struct.cpp.o
[ 96%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/image.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/rectangles.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/object_detection.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/shape_predictor.cpp.o
[ 99%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/correlation_tracker.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib', needed by `dlib.so'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Seems to be unrelated to CMake, doesn't it?

Comment: Do you have python installed in the directory mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Download the source code at the [official website](http://dlib.net/files/dlib-19.4.tar.bz2), then install:

```
tar -jxvf XXXXX.bz2
python setup.py install
```